# What range of orbital elements was available for the Space Shuttle?

Tags: orbit, orbital-maneuver, space-shuttle

What range of orbital elements (*inclination, apogee*, *eccenticity*) was available for the space shuttle?
What range has it really achieved?
What were the engineered limits?

Comment: It depends on the orbiter in question and the year (they differed in mass). ODS made payload (and achievable orbit) smaller; inclination was determined by the range it was launched from (the Cape vs Vandenberg when Vandenberg was allowed).

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the orbiter differences and other nuances. I'd expect the answer to cover all of that. And I specifically asking about the *range*, not constant values. I can remove the 'optimal' if that is misleading.

Comment: References: http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/news/columbia/fr_generic.pdf and http://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf

Comment: The highest circular orbit achievable was around 700 km (with launch due east from the Cape). This was limited by the heat shield (both peak heat flux and total heat flux) and OMS propellant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ORBITAL INCLINATION**:

All the shuttles launched from KSC has a maximum inclination of 57 [degrees](http://www.satobs.org/seesat/Jan-2000/0199.html)(latitudes between 60 N and 60 S) .

> Azimuths greater than 120 degrees to the southeast (i.e., inclinations greater than 39
> degrees) are not allowed because they overfly the Bahamas just off the coast
> of Florida, not to mention the extreme eastern tip of Cuba and Haiti.

**ORBIT**:

usually circular (almost)with the the altitude of 200 km to 600 km

but for [STS-125](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-125)

> Perigee             486 kilometres (302 mi)
>
> Apogee         578 kilometres (359 mi)
>
> Inclination        28.5°
>
> Period          97 min

external source

- http://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/keps/sarex/sts-vec.txt

Comment: If the maximum was 57 degrees, then how did they get a 62 degree inclination?

Comment: That mission used a "dog-leg" ascent profile where the initial azimuth was 57 but the vehicle turned during ascent to the higher inclination once the range safety limitations were cleared.  Very expensive performance-wise.